# Trouble passing a parameter for ManagementObject query in c#

Tags: c#, wmi

This is the code that I have for my query:

```
public String getDriveID()
{
    String wow = @"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\" + @driveID;

    ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject(wow);
    disk.Get();
    Console.WriteLine(disk["Name"]);
    return disk["Name"].ToString();
}
```

And this is what creates the `driveID` String that the method uses:

```
DriveInfo dInfo = therehasgottobeanotherway[driveList.SelectedIndex];

if (dInfo.IsReady) {
    diskWMI dwmi = new diskWMI(dInfo.Name);
}
```

If you're not familiar with the `DriveInfo` class, the `Name` attribute returns the name of the drive, for example `c:\`

I found this code online that does the EXACT same thing I'm trying to do, but I always get an error when I'm trying to use it:

```
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
disk.Get();
Console.WriteLine(disk["VolumeName"]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I bet there is a formatting error happening but I can't figure out what to change.

I'm trying to pass in a drives name where it has `deviceid=`

Comment: Perhaps you are getting an error somewhere else.. can you Debug your code and see where the actual error is happening also if you find the error edit your original post to show the code that's giving you an error

Comment: Whenever I run the code the only error I am getting is invalid parameter.

Comment: I figured it out for you I will put 2 examples below I would suggest making a Method and Pass in the Drive this way you don't have to hard code the Drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string GetHDDSerialNumber(string drive)
{
    //check to see if the user provided a drive letter
    //if not default it to "C"
    if (drive == "" || drive == null)
    {
        drive = "C";
    }
    //create our ManagementObject, passing it the drive letter to the
    //DevideID using WQL
    ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\"" + drive + ":\"");
    //bind our management object
    disk.Get();
    //return the serial number
    return disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
}
```

or for your existing example this will work for you

```
String drive = "c";
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\"" + drive + ":\"");
disk.Get();
Console.WriteLine(disk["VolumeName"]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Sorry I have been away from the code. I see what ya did, I was incorrectly passing a parameter with the :\ giving me trouble.

BTW, what kind of music do you DJ?

And, how is the double quotes valid?

Comment: I Click on my user ID and you will see my url to my music site.. I am glad that I was able to help you get to the correct Solution..

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I can confirm that I took your code and ran the following, worked fine for me:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Management;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
            disk.Get();
            Console.WriteLine(disk["VolumeName"]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It displayed the name in the console window with fail.

Comment: This worked as well for me but what I also had to do is click on References and I added System.Management 4.0 to my references and got no error

Comment: I can confirm the code you posted works too. What I am trying to do is to pass in a different value for the device id. Like I'd wanna be able to pass in z:\ or f:\

Answer (score 0):

remove backslash from the deviceId and it should work. The link you mentioned has a backslash :String drive = @"C:\"; => **String drive = @"C:"**;